# VBA defines wrong last column

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to find last column in the database, but for some reason it stops at column #9 and thinks that it is the last one. There are no blanks in the data to cause this problem. How can I fix it? I know the code is right and it works well in other workbooks, but not this one...

Here's the code itself:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Online - Care").Activate
With Sheets("Online - Care")
    LCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

Comment: When you are far out to the right in row 3 and hit `end-left` manually, where do you end up?

Comment: it takes me to the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
LCol = .cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).column
```

Searches for none blanks and looks for the previous occurrence from the first cell (ie the last occurrence in the sheet).

I am not sure how this deals with whitespace though, I have never actually used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I figured it all out. It's because I defined the same Lcol in several spreadsheets and it was looking for the very last definition of Lcol.

Lesson #1: different spreadsheets, different definition of last column :)

Thank you all for trying to help!